# Função que calcula o fatorial de um número

Tags: c, algoritmo, loop

```
int fatorial(int n, int f){
int resultado;
while(n>1){
f=1;
resultado=(n*f);
f=f-1;
}
return (resultado);
}
int main(void){
int resultado;
int n;
int f;

printf("Digite o numero a ser fatorado:\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
resultado=fatorial(n,f);
printf("%d", resultado);
}
```

Qual o erro do meu código que faz entrar em *loop* infinito?

Comment: já tentou debugar linha a linha pra entender?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Tem muita coisa errada aí. A maioria das variáveis são desnecessárias. Quando está criando o código tem que se perguntar para que precisa daquilo. Se não tem uma resposta não use. Se não puder justificar qualquer coisa no código não use.

Não entendi para que esse parâmetro `f` na função, parece completamente sem sentido, ainda mais que vai inicializar essa variável lá com 1, e um dos erros é fazer isso dentro do `while`. Mas se pensar bem pra que precisa dela? Já tem uma variável que determina onde começa a contagem e pode ir decrementando ela até chegar onde quer. Só preciso de uma outra pra guardar o resultado das multiplicações. Fica tudo mais simples. E no pedido de dado para fazer o fatorial só precisa de uma variável para guardar o valor necessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fatorial(int n) {
    int resultado = 1;
    while (n > 1) resultado *= n--;
    return resultado;
}
int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("Digite o numero a ser fatorado:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", fatorial(n));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/McFS4x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vqgtlyrd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Fatorial.c).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar recursividade tambem.

Olha o exemplo:

```
int factorial(int num){
    if (num == 1 || num == 0){
       return 1;
    }

   return factorial(num - 1) * num;
}
```

> Recursividade: a recursividade é a definição de uma sub-rotina (função
>   ou método) que pode invocar a si mesma.

Se estiver iniciando agora como programadora em algum momento vai se deparar com esse palavra. Em alguns casos é legal utiliza-lá para diminuir linhas de código e treinar bem sua logica, mas é sempre bom analisar o uso de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei alguns erros no seu código, segue o código corrigido:

```
int fatorial(int n){
   int aux = n - 1;

   while(aux > 1){
      n = n * aux;
      aux--;
   }

   return n;
}

int main(void){
   int resultado;
   int n;
   int f;

   printf("Digite o numero a ser fatorado:\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   resultado = fatorial(n);
   printf("%d", resultado);
}
```